# Why does indexOf on an empty array does not return -1?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to check if an array contains a given value:

```
var arr = [];

if (arr.indexOf(2)) {
    console.log('yes');
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tqx7egro/)

Why is the if condition always met, although `arr` does not contain a value of `2`? Shouldn't it return `-1` and therefore nothing should be logged?

Comment: In JavaScript `Boolean(-1) === true`, so `Boolean([].indexof(2)) === true`, but `Boolean([2].indexOf(2)) === false`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you run this code in your browser's console, you'll see that it **does** return -1. However, in a JavaScript if statement, -1 is truthy so the alert will execute. As detailed in this excellent [JavaScript equality table](https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/), there's only a very few values which will evaluate as false in an if statement: `false`, `0`, `""`, `null`, `undefined` and `NaN`.

Answer (score 3):

Your condition should be:

```
if (arr.indexOf(2) >= 0)
```

because in JavaScript, `0` is `false` when coalesced to a boolean, and any other number is considered `true`.

Therefore... `-1` is coalesced to `true`.

```js
alert(!!-1)
```

Answer (score 2):

It does return -1 but -1 in Javascript is considered "truthy".

Try this to see that it is indeed returning -1:

```
var i = arr.indexOf(2);
console.log(i);
```

You need to explicitly compare for non-equality to -1 in your condition.

Here's an updated version of your jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/bmj8y8bj/